# Installation Windows update file (.msu) through GPO to 150 pc

Tags: powershell, windows-update, gpo

I want to update Windows 7 computers from PowerShell 2.0 to 5.1 ([installer link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616)).

As GPO doesn't support the `msu` installer, I created a logon script which runs this msu file (`wusa.exe`). But when a domain user logs in, the installation process stops asking to enter credential for administrator account...

I tried to do a shortcut of this file and `runas /savecredential` but it does not work. Also I tried to put the installation policy to PC startup but nothing happened.

Finally I tried to save the file local to the DC server and local to PC but same issue again!

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on  https://serverfault.com

Answer (score -1):

That is because msi is designed to work within the trustedinstaller service so it is executed using different credentials than the user who is authenticated to the system.

In order to perform an installation in a different way you need the logged user to be included within the local computer Administrators group, in theory it is also possible to use a home-made program or a powershell code that will trigger a launch for the setup program using different credentials trought wmic / wrm. In the past, at windows 2003 server era, I also used tools like remoteexec, psexec but I would not be sure they are still appliable on recent systems.

Personally I always preferred to distribute only msi using the GPO and in case something else need to be installed act remotely using RDP or teamviewer and opening use RUNAS, for example:

```
1 Right Click on Windows Start icon and choose Run

2 Input “CMD” in open box and click “OK”

3 Input: runas /profile /user:AAA@domain.com “C:\wusa.exe”  and press “Enter”

4 Input the password of administrator AAA@domain.com

5 Press “Enter”
```

Indeed take a look to your current antivirus remote agent / management console since some of them like the ESET ERA I am using, has a way to trigger a windows update on-demand.